# TexnicCenter Spelling

Tags: texniccenter, french, spelling, dictionaries

I start using  TexnicCenter (2.02 stable) as an editor to write LateX files. During the installation I make sure to install different languages dictionaries especially the french one. 
When using TeXnicCenter, I have tried several time to switch the spelling (see picture). But it seems like even after changing the spelling options and re-starting the software, the speller checker when writing the text remain set to English dictionary. Do someone actually successfully change the spelling on TeXnicCenter?
[image]

Comment: I have tried that your procedure, but the speller checker remain in english, even if in option spelling-> languague is set to french.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, this is not an issue anymore. The right way to change the speller checker is to go to Project -> Properties and change the project language.